# Mongo aggregate and $group nested array with $lookup

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following Product Schema: (partial, using mongoose)

```
 attributes: [
      {
        set: {
          ref: 'AttributeSet',
          type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
        },
        items: [
          {
            attribute: {
              ref: 'Attributes',
              type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
            },
            values: [
              {
                ref: 'AttributeValues',
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        _id: 0
      }
    ],
```

**example document 1: (partial)**

```
"attributes" : [
        {
            "set" : ObjectId("5ccc079c846de44116182890"),
            "items" : [
                {
                    "values" : [
                        ObjectId("5ccc0900846de441161828a1")
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5dee638d72fa520f53d0d1c4"),
                    "attribute" : ObjectId("5ccc0900846de441161828a0")
                },
                {
                    "values" : [
                        ObjectId("5ccc0a51846de441161828cc")
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5dee638d72fa520f53d0d1c3"),
                    "attribute" : ObjectId("5ccc0a51846de441161828cb")
                },
                {
                    "values" : [
                        ObjectId("5ccc0c7d846de44116182906")
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5dee638d72fa520f53d0d1c2"),
                    "attribute" : ObjectId("5ccc0c7d846de44116182904")
                },
                {
                    "values" : [
                        ObjectId("5ccc0d64846de44116182911")
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5dee638d72fa520f53d0d1c1"),
                    "attribute" : ObjectId("5ccc0d64846de4411618290f")
                },
                {
                    "values" : [
                        ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182892")
                    ],
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5def6acf66910405e07e1e9f"),
                    "attribute" : ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182891")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**example document 2: (partial)**

```
"attributes" : [
        {
            "set" : ObjectId("5ccc079c846de44116182890"), 
            "items" : [
                {
                    "values" : [
                        ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182892")
                    ], 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5dee635c72fa520f53d0d1c0"), 
                    "attribute" : ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182891")
                }, 
                {
                    "values" : [
                        ObjectId("5ccc0900846de441161828a2")
                    ], 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5dee635c72fa520f53d0d1bf"), 
                    "attribute" : ObjectId("5ccc0900846de441161828a0")
                }, 
                {
                    "values" : [
                        ObjectId("5ccc0ea4846de44116182941")
                    ], 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5dee635c72fa520f53d0d1be"), 
                    "attribute" : ObjectId("5ccc0ea4846de44116182940")
                }, 
                {
                    "values" : [
                        ObjectId("5ccc08ba846de4411618289c")
                    ], 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5def56c537e877042d5abeb5"), 
                    "attribute" : ObjectId("5ccc08ba846de4411618289a")
                }, 
                {
                    "values" : [
                        ObjectId("5ccc09ca846de441161828aa"), 
                        ObjectId("5ccc09ca846de441161828a9")
                    ], 
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5def56c537e877042d5abeb4"), 
                    "attribute" : ObjectId("5ccc09ca846de441161828a7")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
```

I want to aggregate and find all products that have attributes and then group the attributes in the output.

**Pipeline:**

```
db.getCollection("products").aggregate(
  [
    { $unwind: "$attributes" },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$attributes",
        attributes: { $first: "$attributes.items" }
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "$attributes" },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "attributes",
        let: { attribute: "$attributes.attribute" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $eq: ["$_id", "$$attribute"]
              }
            }
          },
          { $project: { display_name: 1, _id: 1 } }
        ],
        as: "attrs"
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "attributevalues",
        let: { attribute: "$attributes.values" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $in: ["$_id", "$$attribute"]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        as: "values"
      }
    },
    { $project: { attrs: 1, values: 1, _id: 0 } },
    {
      $group: { _id: "$attrs", items: { $push: "$values" }, total: { $sum: 1 } }
    }
  ],
  {
    allowDiskUse: true
  }
);
```

**Pipeline output:**

```
[{ 
    "_id" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182891"), 
            "display_name" : "Caliber (cal.)"
        }
    ], 
    "items" : [
        [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182892"), 
                "sort_order" : NumberInt(0),
                "label" : "12", 
                "attribute_id" : ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182891")
            }
        ], 
        [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182892"), 
                "sort_order" : NumberInt(0),
                "label" : "12", 
                "attribute_id" : ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182891")
            }
        ]
    ], 
    "total" : 2.0
},
{
    "_id" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc0900846de441161828a0"),
            "display_name" : "Mechanism"
        }
    ],
    "items" : [
        [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc0900846de441161828a2"),
                "sort_order" : NumberInt(1),
                "label" : "Inaction",
                "attribute_id" : ObjectId("5ccc0900846de441161828a0")
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc0900846de441161828a1"),
                "sort_order" : NumberInt(0),
                "label" : "Gas",
                "attribute_id" : ObjectId("5ccc0900846de441161828a0")
            }
        ]
    ],
    "total" : 2.0
}]
```

Problem is that e.x. in 1st element in the array, I have a duplicate inside the `items` array.

**This is the desired output:**

```
[{
    "_id" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182891"),
            "display_name" : "Caliber (cal.)"
        }
    ],
    "items" : [
        [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182892"),
                "sort_order" : NumberInt(0),
                "label" : "12",
                "attribute_id" : ObjectId("5ccc079f846de44116182891"),
                "total": 'current _id total, in this case it should be 2'
            }
        ],
        ...other items goes below, grouped as above
    ]
}]
```

Comment: Please post the sample documents which can produce above output

Comment: I've updated the answer and included document info from 2 products. Thanks

Comment: Unclear... Please try to explain with which field you want to `$group` by... because I can see you have multiple `attributes` fields. One is main and other is inside `attiributes.items` and one more inside `attributes.items.values`

Comment: `attributes.items.values` is the one that must be grouped. Sorry for being unclear, it's a little bit complex schema...

Comment: have you considered that maybe this is not the best schema/structure for this data since you need such complex query pattern?  Or is this sort of aggregation the exception and normally the use of data is very straight forward queries?

Comment: It’s just an exception, almost all other queries are straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the solution to group the values by attribute and values and count the occurrences followed by look up and pushing all the values for the attribute with their count.

```
db.products.aggregate(
[
   {"$unwind":"$attributes"},
   {"$unwind":"$attributes.items"},
   {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$attributes.items"}},
   {"$unwind":"$values"},
   {"$group":{
      "_id":{"attribute":"$attribute","values":"$values"},
      "total":{"$sum":1}
   }},
   {"$lookup":{
      "from":"attributes",
      "let":{"attribute":"$_id.attribute"},
      "pipeline":[
        {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$_id","$$attribute"]}}},
        {"$project":{"display_name":1,"_id":1}}],
      "as":"attrs"
   }},
   {"$lookup":{
      "from":"attributevalues",
      "localField":"_id.values",
      "foreignField":"_id",
      "as":"values"
   }},
   {"$unwind":"$values"},
   {"$addFields":{"values.total":"$total"}},
   {"$group":{
     "_id":{"$arrayElemAt":["$attrs", 0]},
     "values":{"$push":"$values"}
   }}
])
```

Use the below aggregation query. Use $addToSet to keep unique values.

```
db.products.aggregate(
 [
  {"$unwind":"$attributes"},
  {"$unwind":"$attributes.items"},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$attributes.items"}},
  {"$unwind":"$values"},
  {"$group":{
     "_id":"$attribute",
     "values":{"$addToSet":"$values"},
     "total":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$lookup":{
     "from":"attributes",
     "let":{"attribute":"$_id"},
     "pipeline":[
       {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$_id","$$attribute"]}}},
       {"$project":{"display_name":1,"_id":1}}],
     "as":"attrs"
  }},
  {"$addFields":{"attrs":{"$arrayElemAt":["$attrs", 0]}},
  {"$lookup":{
     "from":"attributevalues",
     "localField":"values",
     "foreignField":"_id",
     "as":"values"
   }}
])
```

Old answer

You could use below aggregation query. I tried to clean up your current query and change to group only by values field.

Something like

```
db.products.aggregate(
[
  {"$unwind":"$attributes"},
  {"$unwind":"$attributes.items"},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$attributes.items"}},
  {"$unwind":"$values"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$values",
    "items":{"$first":"$$ROOT"},
    "total":{"$sum":1}
  }},
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"attributes",
    "let":{"attribute":"$items.attribute"},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$_id","$$attribute"]}}},
      {"$project":{"display_name":1,"_id":1}}],
    "as":"attrs"
  }},
  {"$lookup":{
     "from":"attributevalues",
     "localField":"items.values",
     "foreignField":"_id",
     "as":"values"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$values"},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"$arrayElemAt":["$attrs", 0]},
    "values":{"$push":"$values"},
    "total":{"$first":"$total"}
  }},
  {"$addFields":{"_id":0, "attribute":"$_id"}}
])
```

Comment: thanks for replying, I've made the following modifications:  In last `$project`   `$project: { attribute: { $arrayElemAt: ['$attribute', 0] }, values: 1, total: 1, _id: 0 }` since attribute is always 1 (so no array needed) and added `total` in order to bring the number of products that have the `values`. One issue tho, I still get duplicate `attribute` as seen in this screenshot: https://prnt.sc/q9t7l8

Comment: You are welcome. So there is possibility of duplicates in couple of places. one is values and other one is attribute. I added $group on value to filter duplicate values. duplicate attributes are from another value document. how do you want me to filter this out ?

Comment: I can add $group by attributes and collect all the values. Would that work for you ?

Comment: There should be only one `attribute` that has `values`, e.x. `{attribute: {display_name: 'caliber'}, values: [{label: 12}, {label:'32'}]`

Comment: Updated answer to include group by. I think I can simplify it further without needing two groups.

Comment: million thanks, it works like a charm! It could be nice to make it even better.

Comment: You are welcome. I’ve added a variant to have single group i.e group by attribute and use addtoset to keep unique values followed by lookup to get the referenced data.

Comment: can you please edit and rename arrayAtElem to arrayElemAt, and fix last group being closed at `_id` thus getting error `A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.` It won't allow me to edit since it needs to change more than 6 chars.

Comment: you're welcome, one last typo `"_id":{"$arrayElemAt":["$attrs", 0]}}` should be `"_id":{"$arrayElemAt":["$attrs", 0]}`  :)

Comment: is there a way to make `$attribute` an object and not array when using the first snippet of the answer?

Comment: Done. Added `{"$addFields":{"$attrs":{"$arrayElemAt":["$attrs", 0]}}`. Sorry for the typos.

Comment: great! please rename `$attrs` to `attrs` in `$addFields` and everything will be perfect! :)  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204128/discussion-between-stathis-ntonas-and-user2683814).

Comment: Updated answer. Please take a look.